# Meta activity unavailable on Election page... for just one candidate

Tags: support, election

I've voted in the elections, going through the profiles. I also looked at the meta participation and I noticed that one user's meta activity was shown as "meta temporarily unavailable". All of the other candidates had their meta ratios shown.

I refreshed the page and that didn't help. (The candidates were shown in a different order, but the bug was persistent to the same candidate's profile.)

Is this a bug on my end? A bug in SO?

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This indicates that at the time meta information was pulled there was a glitch in the matrix - probably as a result of a build being pushed at that exact moment.  This meta information will be refreshed soon.

Comment: Thanks you for the information. Do you have an approximate timeframe? I just checked again with no luck.

Comment: It will be refreshed in < 1 hour - visit SLaks profile page directly on meta - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/34397/slaks  You should see all of the same information.